# Fog gem leaking memory

Tags: ruby, fog

I have written a script to recursively download through my Rackspace cloudfiles containers and retrieve a copy of every file, so I have a local backup in case Rackspace is hit by meteors and/or hindenbugs.

However, my script is apparently leaking memory at a linear scale when downloading my files.

Basically I have a method that looks like this:

```
def download_file(fog_file, destination_path)
  data = fog_file.body
  File.open(destination_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(data) }
end
```

I understand that due to the nature of Fog, I cannot avoid loading an entire file into memory, but I would imagine that Ruby would release memory (or have the ability to release memory) after each `download_file` invocation. After all, the `data` variable goes out of scope.

Unfortunately, when I look at my system monitoring, the memory usage just keep increasing at a linear pace until it consumes all of my available memory at which point the script crashes.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using Ruby 2.1.2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure why you are leaking ( do you keep a reference to fog_file?) but you can stream fog file downloads (see http://www.kylev.com/2013/05/14/foggy-sponges-and-kittens/ for example)

Comment: Ruby has built in garbage collection after a do/end block regarding File.open.  Try explicitly closing the file and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid to load the entire file in memory in two ways.

First, you can retrieve the file in 100kb(or less) chucks:

```
service = Fog::Storage.new({ provider: 'Rackspace', 
                             # ... auth config
                             connection_options: {chunk_size: 102_400} # 100 KB in bytes                        
})

directory = service.directories.get "dir"

File.open((destination_path, 'w') do | f |
  directory.files.get("my_file_on_cloud.png") do | data, remaining, content_length |
    f.syswrite data
  end
end
```

Second, you can retrieve file url with fog then use OpenUri to download and save the file:

```
require 'open-uri'

file = open(file.public_url).read
File.open(destination_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(file) }
```

The first method writes directly on destination file, the second instead create a `Tempfile` instance(create a temporary file on filesystem). Try both.

Comment: This is an old question and I actually solved the issue by using the first method. Keep in mind that chunk_size (at least for Rackspace) takes bytes not megabytes, so 0.100 probably won't work. I used `connection_options: {chunk_size: 20_971_520}` to get 20 megabytes at a time. It resolved the leak issue.